# jQuery GET overwiting POST

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I've got a simple jQuery script that isn't behaving correctly. What am I doing wrong? The idea is that the user enters a value into a textbox and then clicks a button. The jQuery then uses POST to send the value to a PHP file. The PHP file then runs a simple SQL query and gives a response. jQuery .load is then used to refresh the div containing the original php.

Using Chrome's tools, I've noticed that the response for POST is perfect. However, it then gets overwritten by a GET with no data.

**jQuery**:

```
$("#GOtest").click(function() {
var customer = $("#customer").val();
if (customer == '') {
  $('#alert_formula_save_failed').show();
}
else {
  $.post("../assets/forms/formulations/set_session.php", {
    customer: customer,

    }, function(data) {
      $('#alert_formula_save_success').show();
      $('#dynamic').load('../assets/forms/formulations/set_session.php');
      $('#alert_formula_save_failed').hide();
      setTimeout(function() { $('#alert_formula_save_success').fadeOut('fast'); }, 3000);
  });
}
});
```

**PHP**:

```
 <?php    
$customer = null;
$customer = 'Test' ;
$customer2 = $_POST['customer'] ;

.. db connection bits ;

try 
{
    $PDO =  new PDO( "mysql:host=".$host.";"."dbname=".$dbname, $user, $pass);  
}
catch(PDOException $e) 
{
    die($e->getMessage());  
}
    $PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM db_customers where customer = '$customer' ";
    $stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($id));
    $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $PDO = null;

    $iscurrent  = $data['iscurrent'];

    echo '<br>' ;
    echo 'Response 1-' ;
    echo $iscurrent;
    echo '<br>' ;
    echo 'Response 2-' ;
    echo $customer2 ;

?>
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="testform" name="testform" method="POST"> 
    <button type="button" name="GOtest" id="GOtest" class="btn btn-info">
        <i class="fa fa-frown-o"></i> 
        SET SESSION
    </button>
```

The idea being that 'response 1' just echoes a predefined value. Response 2 should just echo out whatever is typed into the text input box.. but the GET overwrites everything.

Comment: Is your `#GoTest` element a submit button of a form, or an `a` element? Seeing your HTML would help.

Comment: Here is the code for the button. The site uses Bootstrap.
      <button type="button" name="GOtest" id="GOtest" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-frown-o"></i> SET SESSION</button>

Comment: And is that within a `<form>`?

Comment: Try adding `onclick="return false;"` into the `<button>` tag. This should prevent the page from being submitted in any way.

Comment: It is, yes : 
<form id="testform" name="testform" method="POST">

Comment: Why the seconds request for `set_session.php`? `$('#dynamic').load('../assets/forms/formulations/set_session.php');`

Comment: `$('#dynamic').load('../assets/forms/formulations/set_session.php');` That's your GET request with no data; that `.load()` function is a wrapper around an AJAX call. If you've already got the response (you have, it's the `data` variable), stick it straight into that element: `$('#dynamic').html(data);`.

Comment: The idea is to reload set_session to display an updated $customer2 .

Comment: @DanielDunn The idea is to do **one** POST AJAX request, return the correct response to do whatever you need, then use it. If you're issuing another AJAX request to the exact same URL, to get the content that's the result of the first AJAX call, you're doing it very, very wrong.

Comment: You might want to look at this line `$stmt->execute(array($id));` as I have no idea why you are adding a parameter when you are not using one and `$id` does not seem to exists either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "issue" is this line:

```
$('#dynamic').load('../assets/forms/formulations/set_session.php');
```

It uses GET by default.

Try using this in its place:

```
$('#dynamic').html(data);
```